# Powershell Get-Child-Item : how to filter by size?

Tags: bash, powershell

Roughly speaking I want to do the equivalent of **bash**'s:

`find . -name "*portal*" -type f -size +100k`

I've tried:

`Get-ChildItem -Filter "*portal*" -Recurse -File | where-object {Size -gt 10 }`

`Get-ChildItem -Filter "*portal*" -Recurse -File | where-object {Length -gt 10 }`

`Get-ChildItem -Filter "*portal*" -Recurse -File | where-object {$_.size -gt 100 }`

The numbers are low on purpose since I am not sure which units are being used.

But nothing is returned.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- `ls`, `dir`, `gci` are aliases for `Get-ChildItem` and can be used instead.
- use `Length` not `size`.
- In a `where` or `?` (aliases for `Where-Object`) without `{}` use Length, inside curly brackets use `?{$_.Length -gt 10kb}`
- suffixes `kb`, `mb`, `gb`, `tb` and `pb` directly following a number (int/float) are automatically expanded as multiples of 1024 (casing doesn't matter)

---

```
PoSh 02:25:10 C:\> 1kb
1024
PoSh 02:25:18 C:\> 1mb
1048576
PoSh 02:25:29 C:\> 1gb
1073741824
PoSh 02:25:34 C:\> 1tb
1099511627776
PoSh 02:25:40 C:\> 1pb
1125899906842624
```

These are valid
`Get-ChildItem -Filter "*portal*" -Recurse -File | where Length -gt 10kb`

`Get-ChildItem -Filter "*portal*" -Recurse -File | where-object {$_.Length -gt 10mb }`

`Get-ChildItem -Filter "*portal*" -Recurse -File | ? Length -gt 1gb`